# how access localstorage using chrome extension

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am working on a chrome extension and I am able to successfully store information to local storage, but my issue is actually access that information once it's in local storage. What I have not does not return anything just says NULL.

I have two files: options.html, and content.js. The options.html is where the user will input the information to save to local storage and the content.js will access the information to use.

**options.html**

```
$(function() {
    // Insert new buttons (you'd probably not ACTUALLY use buttons, instead saving on blurs or every x seconds)
    $("#save_buttons").after("<input type='submit' value='Save Form' id='saveData'>").after("<input type='submit' value='Clear Saved Data' id='clearData'>");
    $("#saveData").click(function(e) {
        // Don't actually submit form
        e.preventDefault();

        // Bit of generic data to test if saved data exists on page load
        localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");

        // serializeArray is awesome and powerful
        var data = $("#hanes").serializeArray();

        // iterate over results
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            // HTML5 magic!!
            localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
        });
    });

    // Test if there is already saved data  
    if (localStorage.getItem("flag") == "set") {
        // Tell the user
        $("header").before("<p id='message'>This form has saved data!</p>");

        // Same iteration stuff as before
        var data = $("#hanes").serializeArray();

        // Only the only way we can select is by the name attribute, but jQuery is down with that.
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            $("[name='" + obj.name +"']").val(localStorage.getItem(obj.name));
        });
    }

    // Provide mechanism to remove data. You'd probably actually remove it not just kill the flag
    $("#clearData").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem("flag", "");
    });
});


<form id="hanes" name="hanes">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
Address: <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
City: <input type="text" name="city" /><br />
</form>
```

**background.html**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "firstname")
      sendResponse({status: localStorage['firstname']});
    else
      sendResponse({});
});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "lastname")
      sendResponse({status: localStorage['lastname']});
    else
      sendResponse({});
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "firstname"}, function(response) {
  alert(response.status);
});

chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "lastname"}, function(response) {
  alert(response.status);
});
```

Comment: If you look at the [resources tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/resources) on `options.html` do you see the data as expected under localstorage?

Comment: @abraham Yes, I am able to see all data in the resources tab under local storage, and I am able to get it working with `Message Passing`. I updated the code can you explain how I can call each piece of data from the local storage I don't know how to call them all. I only know how to call one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content scripts run in their own little world thats even outside the world of your extension ( [Chrome extension code vs Content scripts vs Injected scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-auto-run-a-function/9916089#9916089)).  Content scripts are unable to access the localStorage of your extension.
So you either need to communicate with the background page using message passing ( http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) or if you really want to avoid using a background page you can use the iFrame trick ( [Options-enabled content-script Chrome extension without background page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033873/options-enabled-content-script-chrome-extension-without-background-page/9579856#9579856)).

Comment: Abraham is right about using the parentheses instead of brackets, but this is the answer. `localStorage` in a Content Script refers to the `localStorage` of the page on which it is injected.

Comment: @PAEz `message passing` works thank you, but how do I access all the data in local storage? I updated my code.

Comment: @Mr.1.0 I didnt try your code, but that looks right to me.  If your asking how to access all of localStorage in one call I guess you could do `JSON.stringify(localStorage)` and send that back to the content script.  Although normally Id just make an object with everything I wanted and send that stringified to the content script.

Answer (score 0):

Use `()` instead of `[]`.

```
var fname = window.localStorage.getItem('firstname');
```